# Why does addReference method not working in symfony?

Tags: symfony, runtime-error, many-to-many

WriterFixures class :

```
$manager->flush();
 $writer = new Writer();
 $writer->setName("Kasza Sandor");
 $manager->persist($writer);
 $this->addReference(self::WRITER_REFERENCE,$writer);
```

BookFixtures class:

```
$book2 = new Book();
    $book2->setTitle("Sapiens");
    $book2->setReleaseYear(2018);
    $book2->setDescription("Ez egy elgondolkodtató könyv");
    $book2->setImagePath("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41NGcHIqqbL._SX375_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg");
   $book2->addWriter($this->getReference(WriterFixtures::WRITER_REFERENCE));
    $manager->persist($book2);
```

Poblem error message

In ReferenceRepository.php line 158:

Reference to "writer" does not exist

Here my github folder all code here
https://github.com/kaszagyerek/books

Comment: In what order do the fixtures run ? Did you add the DependantFixtureInterface ?
Here is the link to the [documentation](https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/current/index.html#loading-the-fixture-files-in-order)

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer for your problem but for others facing the same issue, the reason why the error is thrown is because your "BookFixture.php" file is executed first , because by default Symfony will compile your files in an alphabetical order.

To change this you can choose which files gets compiled before others with implementing the DependentFixtureInterface to your Fixture class like this :

```
namespace App\DataFixtures;

use App\Entity\Products;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class WriterFixture extends Fixture
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager): void
    {
        //code goes here ...
    }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

namespace App\DataFixtures;

use App\Entity\Details;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\DependentFixtureInterface;

class BookFixture extends Fixture implements DependentFixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager): void
    {
        //code goes here ...
    }

    public function getDependencies()
    {
        return [
            WriterFixtures::class,
        ];
    }
}
```

Check Documentation For More Details : https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/current/index.html#loading-the-fixture-files-in-order